# dynamic text size JavaScript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am using the following Javascript to make the font size dynamic. Problem is, it is not working in IE.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Or introduce a fallback?

---

```
<script>
var fontFix = function () {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    document.body.style.fontSize = width + "px";
};
window.addEventListener('resize', fontFix);
window.addEventListener('load', fontFix);
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use a percentage in CSS instead?

Comment: This script allows me to use percentage. And makes the text dynamic.

Comment: Check the values that you're getting for "width"; that might help explain the problem.

Comment: @Pointy Not entirely sure what you mean?

Comment: Use the browser debugger and `console.log()` to check what's in that variable "width" in your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of IE used `attachEvent` method instead of `addEventListener`. To make the approach universal you can use something like this

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', fontFix);
    window.addEventListener('load', fontFix);
} else {    
    window.attachEvent('onresize', fontFix);
    window.attachEvent('onload', fontFix);
}
```

Note: If possible I suggest using jQuery, it takes care of such cross-browser issues beautifully. Using jQuery it would be simple:

```
$(window).bind('resize load', function() {
   $('body').css('font-size', $(window).width())
})
```

Comment: You should clarify, you are using very old versions of Internet Explorer, not the current versions. You should not need to use attachEvent anymore.

Comment: @ChrisLove hence *Older versions of IE...* in my answer